# Pandas replace string in a column as int

Tags: python, pandas

I am a beginner in pandas and python, asking for a little bit help.
Here is my dataset, the k_symbol column labels either UVER or SIPO, I want to replace UVER as int 0, and SIPO as int 1.

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfhcL.png)

I tried dff.replace(to_replace=['k_symbol'], value=[1, 0]), but it does not seem right.
Appreciate for any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this single line to get desired result.

```
df.k_symbol = df.k_symbol.apply(lambda o : 1 if o == 'SIPO' else 0 if o == 'UVER' else o)
```

You can simplify it as below , if all other than SIPO will be 0

```
df.k_symbol = df.k_symbol.apply(lambda o : 1 if o == 'SIPO' else 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

`apply()` functions are notoriously slow, so if you care about speed, consider one of these solutions

### 1) map()

```
df["k_symbol"].map({"UVER":0, "SIPO":1})
```

### 2) boolean to int conversion

```
df["k_symbol"] = (df["k_symbol"] == "SIPO").astype(int)
```

## Timings

```
%%timeit
df["k_symbol"] = (df["k_symbol"] == "SIPO").astype(int)
10 loops, best of 3: 83.3 ms per loop

%%timeit
df['k_symbol'].apply(lambda x : 0 if x == 'UVER' else 1 )
1 loop, best of 3: 550 ms per loop

%%timeit
df["k_symbol"].map({"UVER":0,"SIPO":1})
10 loops, best of 3: 83.6 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(["SIPO","UVER"] * 3, columns=["k_symbol"])

df["k_symbol"].map({"UVER":0,"SIPO":1})
```

Output:
df

```
  k_symbol
0     SIPO
1     UVER
2     SIPO
3     UVER
4     SIPO
5     UVER
```

mapped:

```
0    1
1    0
2    1
3    0
4    1
5    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.loc` :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, "SIPO"], [0, "UVER"], [0, "UVER"], [0, "UVER"], [1, "UVER"],],
    columns=["gender", "k_symbol"],
)

df.loc[df["k_symbol"] == "SIPO", "k_symbol"] = 1
df.loc[df["k_symbol"] == "UVER", "k_symbol"] = 0

print(df)
```

Returning:

```
   gender k_symbol
0       1        1
1       0        0
2       0        0
3       0        0
4       1        0
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can pass an anonymous function (Lambda) stating a condition to check within apply.

```
df['k_symbol'] = df['k_symbol'].apply(lambda x : 0 if x == 'UVER' else 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe a better (faster) way is using `.eq()`:

```
df['k_symbol'] = df['k_symbol'].eq('SIPO').astype(int)
```